# Store the return value from an anonymous function into a variable outside its scope

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

```
$count = 2;
$amt = 4;
$str = function($count, $amt) {
return "There is ". $count . " and " . $amt;
};
echo $str . "!";
```

How do I store the return value from the anonymous function into a variable? I know that the entire function itself is being stored into $str which is why this doesn't work, but is there a way to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply call `$str` as a function:

```
echo $str() . "!"
```

Documentation for anonymous functions as php.net: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Ok, so storing it in a variable would be: `$var = $str()` Thanks

Comment: @KevinDuke Yes, absolutely. Please note that you require 2 arguments passed to your `$str` function; e.g. `$str(2, 'something')`